# How to read PDF document in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

When I click on button need to read the PDF file in windows phone 7, I am saving the PDF file in a folder and given the specified path in Database.

How can I read the PDF document on a windows phone 7?

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 ways to open PDF file on Windows Phone:

1. Use "native" PDF viewer - Adobe Reader

   To do that, you need a location URI of your PDF file, and then you
   can either use the HyperlinkButton

   ```
   <HyperlinkButton Content="Click here to open PDF"
       NavigateUri="URI of your PDF" TargetName="_blank" Margin="10,60,0,0"/>
   ```

   or you could use the WebBrowser task to browse to the PDF which will
   invoke the PDF viewer:

   ```
   WebBrowserTask browser = new WebBrowserTask();
   browser.URL = "URI of your PDF";
   browser.Show();
   ```
2. Use ComponentOne control for viewing PDFs

   http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PdfViewerPhone/

   This will cost you some money, but should work OK.
3. Write your own control for rendering PDFs :)))

Comment: One thing that surely won't work well is loading a browser and passing the base64 encoded PDF (with more than 2048 characters) as the URL using the data url format (data:application/pdf;base64,askduerysdkjfhsf=)